# Getting actual value of array

Tags: perl

I have searched for examples of returning even and odd elements of an array in Perl and came across some examples using map and grep.

```
@array = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
@list = grep {$_ % 2} 0..$#array;
```

I have tried to return `b, d, f` from the given array but it's just returning numbers and not the actual value.

How can I get the actual values back?

Comment: Quick conversion `@list = map $array[$_], grep { $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#array`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an array slice with `grep()` to produce a list of indices.

```
my @array = qw(a b c d e f g);
my @list  = @array[ grep { $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#array ];
```